# How to represent implementing Interface in Sequence Diagram

Tags: interface, uml

I am beginner in UML and now I am creating one sequence diagram, problem is  I would like to implement DAO interfaces according to user input. How can I draw correctly for implementing Interface in sequence diagram.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not draw an interface on a SD. A SD just shows instances (and eventually slots and ports) and messages exchanged along a life line. If you need to show interfaces use a class diagram.